# Android add dividers for a multiple line textView

Tags: android, textview, overwrite, separator

Was overwriting a TextView class, and as I didn't find many sources, I was wondering how to manage to, on a multiple line textView, add a separator (like a simple line) between each line.

Thanks, you can ask for precisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use somethink like this link :

- [Drawing multiple lines in edittext e.g. notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad)

but this is a link in android developer:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NoteEditor.html

Comment: It worked. But I have to say to people trying to do this that my main issue was I had to put the name of the whole package of my extended textview in my xml to name the component. Anyway thanks.