# How to draw multiline Edittext in notepad?

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext

[image]I am creating a notepad and I want to have edit text with multiple horizontal lines on it. As I have done with some but It is displaying line when I click on next or enter to the next line. I want that lines already be there. When I am using layour with android:lines="5". It is displaying picture as I have attached.

Please suggest on the same. thanks[image]

EDITED: My EditText is showing like this!!!! A Huge gap on top. Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
This is the code, based on google's [note editor](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)The output will be shown in the image.When you press the enter,new lines will be added.

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(R.color.edit_note_line); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //int count = getLineCount();

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

For more info,Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad) link.

Comment: Yes Exactly, But the issue is I want to display 10 horizontal lines in edit text. When write some thing only then after pressing enter I am getting new line but I want that lines already shown on on edit text.

Comment: hi, can you please let me know how can i do this?

Comment: @Shweta check the reference link that i have provided.It has 
jkhouw1's explanation that how you can achieve this :)

Comment: It is not displaying lines when I am pressing enter key. How can I increase lines. or should I need to change getLinecount(); method?

Comment: not getting your point. I want some lines visible on layout. It is working but the problem is on Top it is showing empty space. having space.

Comment: I have already attached the screenshot.I tried this class in my example and it works perfectly.Not getting any empty space on top.Kindly update the your answer.What you are getting as a output?

Comment: How these 6 lines are showing on layout, As we have not define any numbering in code?

Comment: Well for just the testing purpose i have added `android:minLines="10"` in xml and it shows me the 1 line with text and 5 blank lines.So total 6 lines.But the problem is this if you are trying to write something on the say 4 or 5th line directly,you can't write it.Its a bit of hack.Try this :)

Comment: I have edited my question please check the screenshot. i am getting the issue regarding edit text box.

Comment: @Sweta I am facing same issue .. Have you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple add this line in your XML
    android:gravity="top|left"

Answer (score 0):

Here , my code will draw 15 lines by default and you can get more lines by pressing Enter :-

```
package com.wysiwyg.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LineEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;
    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LineEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
        setMinLines(15);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;
        if(getLineCount() > count){
            count = getLineCount();
        }
        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
        }

        // Finishes up by calling the parent method
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```