# How do I create horizontal lines in multiline edittext on each line using xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-styles

[image]

I have `EditText` in xml.
I want to create layout like this using xml or styles. how do I do this. please guide me

Comment: can saw this stack post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad

Comment: I saw this post. but is it possible to create this type of layout using xml. @Dinesh

Comment: it's not possible using xml files you need custom edit text java class ok!

Comment: ok.. fine. thanks for your response.

Comment: thanks, if I need I ask Definitely.. @Dinesh