# EditText with lines like notepad android

Tags: android, android-edittext, notepad

I have use custom `EditText` like notepad from the link [Custom EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad/5972652#5972652)

The text entered on the custom EditText doesn't appears correctly on the lines it contains . It some time appears on the line or below the line , unexpected behaviour

My output   [Click here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15920952562/) !

Required output   [Click here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15919657741/) !

Please help me in this case .

LineEditText.java

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0")); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //int count = getLineCount();

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_edit_story"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/txt_image"
                 android:padding="10dip"
                 android:layout_margin="10dip"
                 android:background="@drawable/relative_lined_edittext_border">

             <com.rb.lined.edittext.LinedEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_story"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"                
                android:background="@null"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:minLines="10"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:text="Story : " />

             </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please attach the code?

Comment: posted , pls have a look...

Comment: `Required output Click here !`. ??? Why is that without any text? What should be ok there? How can we know how you require it? Who is drawing the text in the first picture? I see no code for that.

Comment: The text "Story : " doesn't contains under line in Required output, this is the thing I needed ..Also My Output contains default blue color EditText border which I don't required.

Comment: Thank you, from your question i get my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Desabeling Red underline you can put like

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

or

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

and for removing blue line this may help.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Example

```
   <com.example.lineedittextdemo.LineEditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_story"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:minLines="10"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
    android:text="Story : \n" />
```

Comment: whwn I use android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
or

android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"  I don't get Enter key in keyboard

Comment: I don't get Enter key in keyboard

Comment: I used android:singleLine="false" . still no result

Comment: ok ..leave it ... Can u help me to get minimum 10 lines in custom edit text visible by default

Comment: it's working for me.
you must be using wrap_content for height , may be that's why it's not working.
put   android:minLines="10"

Comment: updated the xml file code . pls see . not works for me .

Comment: check my updated xml. It'll 100% work as it works here.

Comment: see my screen shot [link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/15922375015/) . many space above EditText and not minLines=10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65957/discussion-between-karthik-kolanji-and-mohammad-khatri).

Comment: please tell me solution i'm also getting many spaces above edittext, how to solve this issue..?????

Comment: i got it, it was because i didn't set the gravity, i just add this line and it removes all spaces above it,  android:gravity="top"

Comment: I am using this code but it has blank space at the top.