# Multiline Edittext with Horizontal Lines

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I am making a Assignment don't know how to add a multilines edittext follow this one Tutorial but don't know how to implement it in MainActivity class

[Drawing multiple lines in edittext e.g. notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad)

i am using following class

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {

    private Rect mRect;
    private Paint mPaint;

    // we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRect = new Rect();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      //  mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor()); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //int count = getLineCount();

        int height = getHeight();
        int line_height = getLineHeight();

        int count = height / line_height;

        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

        Rect r = mRect;
        Paint paint = mPaint;
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
            baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

and i have following xml view wanted to inflat them via this class

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</LinearLayout>
```

multilinedittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/multiline_exdittext_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edittxt_multilines"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Whats your mistake

Your custom class is `public class LinedEditText extends EditText`

1. **Did you call this in your XML**

Just Change your **EditText Xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/multiline_exdittext_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.LinedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edittxt_multilines"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now it's working thanks but edittext showing in middle why? i want start lines form start of activity and then soon would you suggest me a good solution for this also @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @Ahmad.Aslam90 Glad to hear .You can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:lines="8"
    android:minLines="6" 
    android:gravity="top|left" 
    android:maxLines="10" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```

Comment: not a proper answer i am looking for horizontal lines in edittext from top to bottom only single line is appearing at bottom and edittext in is also appearing in middle

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml to this

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/multiline_exdittext_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<your.packagename.LinedEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/edittxt_multilines"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```