# EditText with multiple lines, like a notepad

Tags: android

I'm following the example given by [max4ever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6111460/8199772) where he showed how to achieve what I'm looking for. I create a custom `EditText` class:

```
public class LinedEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

// we need this constructor for LayoutInflater
public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //int count = getLineCount();

    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();

    int count = height / line_height;

    if (getLineCount() > count)
        count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

Then I'm adding it to my layout `.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapp.com.test.NotesLayout">

    <myapp.com.test.LinedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem I'm having is that the `EditText` only starts in the middle of the view like this:

[image: preview]

So, my question is, how can I adjust this custom `EditText` so that it shows on top/from the start of the view?

---

**HOW I FIXED IT**

I changed my `xml` to this

```
<myapp.com.test.LinedEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
    android:gravity="top"
    />
```

Setting `android:gravity="top"` is why it was starting in the middle of the view. Thank you for all the contributions.

Comment: I'd troubleshoot by setting the background to a solid color like "#FFFF00" and seeing if it's an issue with the line drawing, or the layout

Comment: have you tried  <myapp.com.test.LinedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

Comment: @SelaliAdobor if I set the background color, the whole screen gets filled.

Comment: @OmarHayat that didn't work, wrap_content makes the height to 0dp, the lines gets drawn depending on the height.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

in your custom `Edittext` in your layout file.This will yield the desired result.

Comment: @ClassA Earlier I mistook parent layout as LinearLayout. There is no such thing layout_gravity in relative layout.

Comment: I tried your new edit, but if you look at the custom class I added in my question, the lines are drawn depending on the height of the view, so making it `wrap_content` is basically making the height 0dp.

Comment: @ClassA WRAP_CONTENT means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding). It's not the same as 0dp.

Comment: @ClassA Setting height or width as 0dp is only relevant for linear layout.  And in that case too it should be used along with layout_weight.

Comment: I know the purpose of `wrap_content`. What I'm say is that the amount of lines that are being drawn depends on the height of the view. Look at the custom editText above `int count = height / line_height;` so in other words if I make the view `wrap_content` then only one line will be drawn. That is not what I want, I want the whole view to be filled with lines like a notepad. From the top to the bottom, not starting in the middle of the screen.